# how to get specific list with all data from a queryset django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

on server sends this data:

```
Object { categoryes: Array[2], brands: Array[2], discount_list: "all", category_slug: "accessories", category_of_relationsheep: "m" }
```

if i print request.POST in server side i got this:

```
<QueryDict: {'categoryes[]': ['Accessories', 'Bands'], 'brands[]': ['Nike', 'HBO'], 'discount_list': ['all'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['S7MXVEdQLd6u0fr4FugEwlupa45oChmw3TeItB4BEUHUHSsxrmVRuAcAhFxYQfpk'], 'category_slug': ['accessories'], 'category_of_relationsheep': ['m']}>
```

hot i can get a list for example "categoryes[]" (but why it called like this with brackets?)

ok if i do like this:
print(request.POST.get("categoryes[]")) it will give the only last object,

how to get full list? specific like cotegoryes? if make like

```
for keys, values in request.POST.items():
    print(values)
```

it print me all values in this dict, but i don't know from where this values? if i make this:

```
for keys, values in request.POST.items():
        if 'categoryes[]' == keys:
            print(values)
```

it give the same only one object related to categoryes but in this list more than 1 object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [getlist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

```
request.POST.getlist('categoryes[]')
```

Answer (score 1):

When accessing `request.GET` and `request.POST`, you don't get a regular dictionary, you get a [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) object. When accessed as a dictionary, it returns the last value for a key. If you want the full list, use the [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) method, for instance:

```
request.POST.getlist("somekey")
```

> Returns a list of the data with the requested key.